# How to deploy BizTalk 2020 SSO Application with BizTalk Application Projects using Azure DevOps Release Pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I am looking for a way to deploy a BizTalk 2020 application and the SSO affiliate application along with it.

Until BizTalk 2016, BTDF was used to deploy SSO applications, but in BizTalk 2020 the BTDF is not supported yet. Is there a way that I can use .btaproject to automate the SSO application deployment?

Or do I have to use the PowerShell Script method as one of the tasks in DevOps Release pipeline after the "Deploy BizTalk Server Application" Task?

I have already gone through [Configure automatic deployment with Visual Studio Team Services in BizTalk Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/configure-automatic-deployment-with-visual-studio-team-services-in-biztalk), but it does not talk about importing SSO application.

I am looking for the solution as part of my project about upgrading BTS 2016 apps to BTS 2020 apps.

Comment: How do you define the build definitions of your pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

> Until BizTalk 2016, BTDF was used to deploy SSO applications, but in
> BizTalk 2020 the BTDF is not supported yet. Is there a way that I can
> use .btaproject to automate the SSO application deployment?
>
> Or do I have to use the PowerShell Script method as one of the tasks
> in DevOps Release pipeline after the "Deploy BizTalk Server
> Application" Task?

According to latest update from [this ticket](https://github.com/BTDF/DeploymentFramework/issues/464#issuecomment-660840528). the BTDF has started to support BizTalk 2020.

So if you have configured a [self-agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install) which downloads this v5.8.0 release, you can try deploy the SSO via [Command-line task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).